# Date Comparison in Select Query Returns False Results

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using following query to display the records.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM episode where episodeDate < '$loaddate' 
and dramaID != (select dramaID from drama where popularity = '5') 
and dramaID != (select dramaID from drama where popularity = '6') 
order by episodeDate desc");
  //number of rows
 echo $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Where loaddate is a DATE VARIABLE in mysql database. So is episodeDate. Now, the problem is that the $rowCount returns '0' wherease the database has more than 15 records with episodeDate less than the variable loaddate.

What could be the problem? The connection is ok and the query is not returning any error either.

Comment: Have you tried running the query on PhpMyadmin? It's probably a logical error.

Comment: Please check the date format of episodeDate and this $loaddate. Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 sub queries are easily replaced with a join, and they only work where the subquery returns one row: the query will still run in instances were both return one.

Ensure that your date is of format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS":

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "
SELECT * 
FROM episode
INNER JOIN drama 
ON episode.dramaID = drama.dramaID 
AND drama.popularity NOT IN ('5','6')
WHERE episode.episodeDate < '$loaddate' 
ORDER BY episode.episodeDate DESC");
//number of rows
echo $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I learned a better way of writing sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the date comparition has to do something with "no results". It would be interesting to find out how many records select the other two subqueries select dramaID from drama where popularity = '5' and select dramaID from drama where popularity = '6'. 
If they bring one record each then try

```
"SELECT * FROM episode where episodeDate < '$loaddate' order by episodeDate desc"
```

If not you probably need to change the query to

```
"SELECT * FROM episode where episodeDate < '$loaddate' 
and dramaID not in (select dramaID from drama where popularity = '5') 
and dramaID not in (select dramaID from drama where popularity = '6') 
order by episodeDate desc"
```

Comment: Thanks bro! it worked. But i still don't get what was wrong with my query. Can you explain it for me?

Comment: That's good! Well the "equal" or "not equal" operator is used to compare two "things" like `dramaID = 554`. When you wish to compare with a number of values use 'in' ot 'not in' operator like `dramaID in (123,456,789)`. Sometimes instead of a fixed values you may have a select sub-query like above.

Comment: Great! Now I understand as well :) Thank you